# Finding the potential function of $F$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

$F= \langle ye^{xy}+x^2,xe^{xy}+2y \rangle$. Find the potential function of $F$.

**My Try:**

$\varphi_x=f(x,y)=ye^{xy}+x^2 $ and $\varphi_y=g(x,y)=xe^{xy}+2y$

Now integrated the first equation with respect to $x$

$$\int\varphi_xdx=\int ye^{xy}+x^2dx=\frac{x^3}{3}+e^{xy}+c(y)$$

To find $c(y)$, I differentiated with respect to $y$
$$\varphi_y=xe^{xy}+c^1(y)=xe^{xy}+2y$$
So, from above $c^1(y)=2y$

$$\int2ydy=y^2+k$$
where k is constant and let $k=0$

So, finally I got the potential function as $\frac{x^3}{3}+e^{xy}+y^2$

**Is my above attempt correct?**

Comment: Try computing the gradient of $\frac{x^3}{3}+e^{xy}+y^2$. Do you recover $F$? Also, you could leave $k$ as a constant to have the general potential function.

Comment: @Dave Thanks, for suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, except that you do not need to force $k=0$, the solution is just

$$
\phi(x, y) = \frac{x^3}{3} + e^{xy} + y^2 + \color{blue}{k}
$$